# Rotating image/video about an axis within xy-plane in FCP

Tags: editing, final-cut-pro-x, effects, special-effects, visual-effects

Is it possible to animate a photo/video so that it continuously rotates about an axis within the xy-plane? For example, rotate it about the y-axis. I know how to regularly rotate a video (rotation about z-axis), and I know you can keyframe using distort with keyframe, but was wondering if there is a way to continuously have a shape rotating about a vertical axis. This would be like 3D-rotation.

For example, having the image of a card continuously "spin" vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to use keyframes than it sounds more like a job for Motion or you might be lucky and find a plug-in for this behaviour. 
I couldn’t think of anything else than keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

FCPX doesn't have this behavior built in - My suggestion is to build the effect in Motion using either the spin behavior or keyframes and `dropzones` (placeholder layers), and export as an FCPX Template. You can then use it repeatedly from the `effects` pane in FCPX directly.

[Spin Behavior](https://help.apple.com/motion/mac/5.4.2/#/motn1374713f)

[Motion -> FCPX Templates](https://help.apple.com/motion/mac/5.4.2/#/motn72925de5)